# How to organize images (and other static content files) for website?

Tags: image, web, filesystems

I work on e-shop, which contains large amounts (tens of thousands) of product images in different sizes. What is the best way to save so many files?
I was thinking about something like this:
public/products/files/(imageId/1000)/imageId/350x350/fileName.jpg

Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to have the images structure as :

```
--public
----product
----images
------35x35
-----------product1.jpg
-----------product2.jpg
-----------product3.jpg
------75x75
-----------product1.jpg
-----------product2.jpg
-----------product3.jpg
------135x175
-----------product1.jpg
-----------product2.jpg
-----------product3.jpg
```